# "Department A in/at/of School of B in/at/of University C"?

Tags: writing

In writing (such as for statement of purpose in PhD application), how would you choose prep. in following or similar cases:

> the department of A **in/at/of**  School of B **in/at/of** University of C ....

Alternatively what do you usually write in such situation?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about English Language Usage or English Language Learners SE.

Comment: Perhaps, the department of A at C University School of B.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with the migration from Academia (I would have suggested a migration in other direction), but I'll provide an answer so the O.P. doesn't feel like a ping-pong ball.

Comment: See also ELU, [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/7382/24489) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/103946/24489).

Answer (score 1):

There are three entities in question. There is the name of the institution:

> Yale University
>   Massachusetts Institute of Technology
>   State University of New York – Stony Brook
>   John Abbott College
>   National University of Singapore

There is the name of the department:

> Department of Secondary Education and Youth Services
>   Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering
>   Department of Pure and Applied Science
>   Department of Chemistry
>   Department of Philosophy

There is the name of the school:

> The McDonough School of Business
>   The Geisel School of Medicine
>   Abraham S. Fischler School of Education
>   School of Psychotherapy & Psychology
>   School of Pure and Applied Physics

Insofar as I understand it, there's a strong correlation between the ***departments*** of an institution, and their ***schools***, and a professor might associate herself with a particular department, or a particular school, **but not necessarily both**.

> Ann Haslett, School of Fine Arts, Quinnipiac University
>   Ann Haslett, Department of Music, Quinnipiac University

Moreover, I usually see such references listed using commas, not prepositions:

> George McHarris, Pratt School of Engineering, Duke University
>   George McHarris, Department of Mechanical Engineering & Materials Science, Duke University

However, I suppose there might be exceptions to my one-but-not-both assertion:

> Ann Haslett, School of Fine Arts, Department of Music, Quinnipiac University
>   George McHarris, Pratt School of Engineering, Department of Mechanical Engineering & Materials Science, Duke University

Now, getting back to the heart of your question, if I wanted to string this information together using prepositions, I would do it like this:

> I worked for the Civil Engineering School **in** the Department of Engineering **at** the University of Suffolk.

In other words, I would say the school is **in** the department, and the department is **at** the school.

Comment: In your last lines, isn't a department in a school, instead of a school in a department, because a school hosts many departments?

Comment: @Tim - "school" in that context doesn't refer to the university (which is why I spent so much time on my preamble). An engineering department might have a School of Mechanical Engineering, a School of Electrical Engineering, and a School of Civil Engineering.

Answer (score 0):

> the Department of German in the College of Letters and Sciences at the University of Montasota

or

> The University of Montasota's Department of German in the College of Letters and Sciences

---

Note: I personally feel like X Department sounds better than Department of X, at least in this context.

> Chemistry Department versus Department of Chemistry

Comment: If the department is formally known as the Department of Chemistry, then I think it might be better to use lower-case when using that "X Department" form; in other words: _the Department of Chemistry at the University of Washington_, vs. _the Chemistry department at the University of Washington_.