# "I'm a student at/from/of/in the XYZ department?

Tags: prepositions

**Question:** If I'm pursuing studies at/in the XYZ department, what is the correct preposition for the following sentence?

> I'm a student [at / in / from / of] the XYZ department

There are related questions here on ELL, but they are mostly about whether I'm studying "at" a<del>n</del> *university*, not a department from a<del>n</del> university. Googling I could find all of these prepositions being used by students in leading English speaking universities.

Related:
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/100972/67575
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/15027/67575
https://english.stackexchange.com/a/7408/229087

Comment: You are studying at **a** university. The use of **a** or **an** depends on the pronunciation of the letter that follows, not of the letter itself. We don't use **an** when the following **u** is pronounced **you**. So we speak of **a uniform** but **an unfortunate incident**.

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you! I initially wrote "a university", but edited right afterwards. Good to know this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is:

#### What department are you in?

The answer could be:

- I’m a student at the Computer Science Department.

Meaning: this answers the question exactly by quoting the name of the department. The asker gets his answer and is now assured that there is indeed a Department in your college with the name "Computer Science".

Or

- I'm a student in Computer Science.

Meaning: this tells about the stream of learning. There could be multiple departments under this stream. It's a generic answer. The asker gets a general understanding about what your department is all about. But he doesn't yet know what exactly the name of the department is.

or

- I'm a student in the ComputerScience department.

#### The role of in/at changes with the context.

Comment: Thank you! But would it also be correct to say "I'm a student *in* the Computer Science department"?

Comment: It certainly would be correct, and what most people would be likely to say.

Comment: @flen yes,thts also correct.

Comment: @AdityaPatnaik could you please edit your answer to include this? Then I can mark it as the answer to my question

Comment: done @flen, hope the answer helped you.

Comment: Thanks! I'd still like to know though if "from" and "of" could be used at all, but it's ok to leave this out

Comment: from/of can also be used here, however the usage would be situational. As in with "i'm a student of xyz department" ,here the emphasis is on you hailing from the xyz department in the context of (one department out of many departments within an institution (say)) , highlights your relationship with the dept and doesn't say anything about it being your primary line of study which is depicted in (i'm a student in Computer Science)